# ASP.NET MVC with alternate windows credentials

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am logged in into my machine using windows domain account i.e. MyDomain/user1.

However I would like to run my ASP.net MVC application using different domain account i.e. MyDomain/user2.

I would not want to impersonate in web.config.

Is there any other way to tell the browser that it should be using credentials of user2?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows try this: `shift+<right click>` in the start-menu when you start the browser and choose "**run as different user**"